# $A.util.toggleClass is not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components

This is the child component i am use the div with the aura:id but this is not working.

```
    <div class="slds-section">
    <h3 class="slds-section__title">
        <button aria-controls="accordion-details-01" aria-expanded="false" class="slds-button slds-section__title-action" onclick="{!c.helperFun}">
            <!-- <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showhideRound}"> -->
                <lightning:icon class="slds-show" iconName="utility:chevrondown" size="x-small" alternativeText="Indicates approval" aura:id="articleOne"/>
                <!-- <aura:set attribute="else"> -->
                    <lightning:icon class="slds-hide" iconName="utility:chevronright" size="x-small" alternativeText="Indicates approval" aura:id="articleOne"/>
                <!-- </aura:set> -->
            <!-- </aura:if> -->
            <span style="padding-left: 10px;" class="slds-truncate" title="Accordion summary">Bid Round {!v.key}</span>
        </button>
    </h3>
</div>

<!-- <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showhideRound}"> -->
    <!--start -->
    <div aura:id="articleOne">
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_resizable-cols slds-table_fixed-layout slds-no-row-hover" role="grid" 
           style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(221, 219, 218);
                  border-left: 1px solid rgb(221, 219, 218);">
        <thead>
            <tr style="line-height: 2; " class="slds-text-title_caps">
                <th  scope="col" style="text-align: center;">
                    <span class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Counterparty Name</span>
                </th>
                <th style="text-align: center;" scope="col">
                    <span class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Bid Round Min</span> 
                </th>
                <th style="text-align: center;" scope="col">
                    <span class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Bid Round Max</span>                         
                </th>
                <th style="text-align: center;" scope="col">
                    <span class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Bid Date</span> 
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <aura:iteration items="{!v.value}" var="key" >

            <tbody>
                <tr class="slds-hint-parent">

                    <td role="gridcell">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" style="text-align: center;" title="Acme">
                            <ui:outputText value="{!key.Name+key.SL_Mandate_Counterparty__r.Company__r.Name}" />   

                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td role="gridcell">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="4/10/15">
                            <!--<ui:inputNumber value="{!key.SL_Bid_Round_Min_MM__c}" required="true"/>
                            --><ui:inputCurrency class="field" value="{!key.SL_Bid_Round_Min_MM__c}"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td role="gridcell">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Value Proposition">
                           <!-- <ui:inputNumber value="{!key.SL_Bid_Round_Max_MM__c}" required="true"/>
                            --><ui:inputCurrency class="field" value="{!key.SL_Bid_Round_Max_MM__c}"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td role="gridcell">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="30%">
                            <ui:inputDate aura:id="expdate" class="field" value="{!key.SL_Bid_Round_Date__c}" displayDatePicker="true" /> 
                        </div>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </aura:iteration>

    </table>
    </div>
```

Controller.js

```
helperFun : function(component, event, helper) {
 var acc = component.find('articleOne');

        for(var cmp in acc) {
        $A.util.toggleClass(acc[cmp], 'slds-show');  
        $A.util.toggleClass(acc[cmp], 'slds-hide');  
   }
},
```

Comment: What you want to toggle on "articleOne" div?

Comment: Yes i want <div> hide and show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$A.util.toggleClass()` method is used to remove the class if it's already set to the element or add the class if it doesn't exist.

On your `div` element, there's none of the two classes `slds-show` and `slds-hide`.

So your code will add the two classes to the `div`.

If you want to hide the `div` first, then show it when it's hidden, you will have to, by default, add the `slds-show` class to the `div`. Like this:

```
<div aura:id="articleOne" class="slds-show">
```

Comment: Hey Martin,
The arrow icons are hide and show, but div is still not hide and show can you please help

Comment: Sorry I missed something on your code. I updated my answer.